# How to get the current IO utilization in percentage from the command line on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, io, wmic

I already know how to get the **CPU** usage percentage:

```
wmic cpu get loadpercentage
```

That returns:

```
LoadPercentage
21
```

But what about the **IO**? Meaning the total **disk** utilization in percentage, or one per disk. Preferably both.

I have searched long and hard and even asked people on IRC without finding this out. I also tried to dig in `wmic` but couldn't find anything such as `wmic io get loadpercentage`.

The `Task Manager` gives this information visually in a GUI. I need it in text format (I'm going to regularly fetch it to enter into my database).

I do not wish to install extra software.

Comment: I don't think you can pull that from the command line like `iotop` in Linux would do.  The resource monitor is about as close as it comes I think (for built-in).  Also, using WMI comes with a hit too screwing your numbers.

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell's `Get-Counter` might do what you're looking for:

> To get the disk performance using PowerShell, we need to use the
> Performance counter of the disk. There are performance counters
> available for the Physical disk or the logical disk. To check what the
> disks related counter sets are available we can use the below command,
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> CounterSetName
> ```
>
> **Output**
>
> ```
> CounterSetName
> -------------- 
> FileSystem Disk Activity 
> Storage Spaces Virtual Disk 
> LogicalDisk 
> PhysicalDisk
> ```
>
> We will use a Logical disk to get more
> information about it. We will retrieve its counter first.
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> Get-Counter -ListSet LogicalDisk | Select -ExpandProperty Counter
> ```
>
> **Output**
>
> [image: image1]
>
> We need to retrieve the Disk read time counter,
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> Get-Counter -Counter '\LogicalDisk(*)\% Disk Read Time'
> ```
>
> **Output**
>
> [image: image2]
>
> The below command will retrieve the 2 sample counts with 2 sample
> intervals.
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> Get-Counter -Counter '\LogicalDisk(*)\% Disk Read Time' -MaxSamples 2 -SampleInterval 2
> ```
>
> To get the continuous intervals, use the below command.
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> Get-Counter -Counter '\LogicalDisk(*)\% Disk Read Time' -Continuous
> ```

Source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-the-disk-performance-using-powershell